# Scrollable tbody td width not taking full space after providing width

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am having scrollable tbody with a fixed header. Column is not aligning properly even after providing width in td. I don't need to add extra div to achieve same.

```css
table.tables {
  width:590px;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}
table.tables thead {
  display: table;
}
table.tables tbody {
  display: block;
}
table.tables thead {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background: aqua;
}
.tables tbody {
  height: 200px;      
  overflow-y: auto; 
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
table.tables tbody tr {
  display:table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
table.tables thead tr {
  display:table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap"> 
  <table class="tables"> 
    <thead> 
      <tr>
        <th width="40%">Header1</th>
        <th width="40%">Header2</th>
        <th width="20%">Header3</th>
      </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="40%">Value1</td>
        <td width="40%">Value2</td>
        <td width="20%">Value3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think there's a `width` issue. Both header and body columns take the same width respectively, but due to differences in alignment they seem a bit off.

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal I need first-row column and all row column must be aligned with thead column. No center.

Comment: @Narxx no it is not alligning

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal it is aligned, but the scrollbar could cause it to look like it's not. To prove my point, add `text-align: center` to the `<tbody>` element and see for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```css
table.tables {
  width: 590px;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}

table.tables > thead{display: table;}
table.tables > tbody{display: block;}

table.tables > thead {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% - 17px); /* 17px scroll-bar width */
  background: aqua;
}

table.tables > thead > tr > th {
  text-align: left; /* the default value for 'th' is center */
}

.tables tbody {
  height: 200px;      
  overflow-y: auto; 
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

table.tables > tbody > tr {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

table.tables > thead > tr > th:first-child {width: 40%}
table.tables > thead > tr > th:nth-child(2) {width: 40%}
table.tables > thead > tr > th:nth-child(3) {width: 20%} /* can also use :last-child */

table.tables > tbody > tr > td:first-child {width: 40%}
table.tables > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) {width: 40%}
table.tables > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3) {width: 20%} /* can also use :last-child */

table.tables > thead > tr {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Still here just in case you make up your mind.
tbody > tr > td {
  text-align: center;
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="wrap"> 
  <table class="tables"> 
    <thead> 
      <tr>
        <th>Header1</th>
        <th>Header2</th>
        <th>Header3</th>
      </tr> 
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>Value3</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
      <td>Value1</td>
      <td>Value2</td>
      <td>Value2</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
      <td>Value1</td>
      <td>Value2</td>
      <td>Value2</td>

      </tr><tr>
      <td>Value1</td>
      <td>Value2</td>
      <td>Value2</td>

      </tr><tr>
      <td>Value1</td>
      <td>Value2</td>
      <td>Value2</td>

      </tr><tr>
      <td>Value1</td>
      <td>Value2</td>
      <td>Value2</td>

      </tr><tr>
      <td>Value1</td>
      <td>Value2</td>
      <td>Value2</td>

      </tr><tr>
      <td>Value1</td>
      <td>Value2</td>
      <td>Value2</td>

      </tr><tr>
      <td>Value1</td>
      <td>Value2</td>
      <td>Value2</td>

      </tr><tr>
      <td>Value1</td>
      <td>Value2</td>
      <td>Value2</td>

      </tr><tr>
      <td>Value1</td>
      <td>Value2</td>
      <td>Value2</td>

      </tr><tr>
      <td>Value1</td>
      <td>Value2</td>
      <td>Value2</td>

      </tr><tr>
      <td>Value1</td>
      <td>Value2</td>
      <td>Value2</td>

      </tr><tr>
      <td>Value1</td>
      <td>Value2</td>
      <td>Value2</td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

By default `td`'s align text left and `th`'s align it center. To align both vertically you need to deduct 17px width of the scroll-bar from 100% and align `th`'s left.